# System Seller Firmware Update Policy IBM

Tags: ibm, update, firmware, reseller

I've heard that IBM expects from their sellers/partners to update machines before shipping to customers to the most recent firmware (uEFI/AMM/IMM/RSA etc.) releases. Can anyone comment on that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as a reseller, no they don't expect us to update machines before shipping them out.

However, we know that doing so tends to make customers happier, so we either:

- Update the machines to the latest firmware
- Flash the firmwares to certain versions for certain customers

*(we're putting the VA into VAR :) )*

Answer (score 1):

If you're a reseller/partner, ask IBM yourself. If you're buying from someone, ask them. Or just check/update all that yourself when you do the build, which is what I have always done.

Answer (score 0):

We don't purchase any integration or other services from our IBM reseller.  Our blade servers come in pieces for us to assemble, test and bring on-line.  They come with whatever firmware they had when the left IBM, which may have been months before due to the reseller's reseller stocking in their warehouse.